# Shopping plugin with user groups

Tags: users, e-commerce

We need to implement different user groups on our new WP-site so every group has it's own price for every product. For example: "retail customers" and "wholesale customers".

Is there an appropriate solution that works out of the box?

If not, what approach should you recommend to achieve this? Maybe some combination of plugins will do?

We really don't want to create separate domains or to have duplicate items in our shop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if you are setting up a new e-commerce site or a trying to change an existing one.

If you are setting up a new site from scratch ... then WooCommerce has a premium plugin called [Dynamic Pricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/) which can create different pricing for different types of users.

Comment: Thank you Damien, looks like this plugin is all we needed. Of course we creating a new website from scratch (in other case i would've highlighted the details).